# Complex Gaussian Channel + AWGN noise

Tags: gaussian

If I define a channel to have complex Gaussian coefficients, do I still need to add noise to the signal passing through this channel using the command "awgn" or would that be redundant?

Comment: Physical channels themselves are relatively free of _additive white Gaussian noise_ and most of the AWGN that is in mathematical models of channels arises from the thermal noise in the front end of the receiver. When you "define" a channel to have complex Gaussian coefficients, what you are modeling is the _fading_ in the physical medium of the wireless channel (caused by ionospheric or tropospheric scatter or reflection off a non-specular surface such as the ocean), and the receiver noise must still be included separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you still need to add noise to the signal. When you have complex Gaussian coefficients, it says about the probability distribution of the filter coefficients. You still need to add the noise after the filtering process.